# Does Dagster-cloud support autoscaling directly?

Tags: autoscaling, dagster

I found in Dagster's documentation a https://docs.dagster.io/deployment/guides/kubernetes/customizing-your-deployment#per-job-kubernetes-configuration

On auto scaling using Kubernetes.

Does Dagster contain a direct method to perform that auto-scaling? (Without Kubernetes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, in ECS, Dagster receives a [cluster ID](https://docs.dagster.io/dagster-cloud/deployment/agents/amazon-ecs/configuration-reference#per-deployment-configuration) in its running configuration, and uses machines in that cluster of the suitable parameters. (So, if you had cluster A, with machine types X,Y, and request to use X machine, Y machines would be ignored)